# python - iteration by date and time - half hour

Tags: python, datetime

I think about how to iterate by data and time in following way:

```
2016-06-10,00:00
2016-06-10,01:30
2016-06-10,02:00
2016-06-10,02:30
....
```

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Have you tried to use Pandas? It's very easy to do this with Pandas.

Comment: Not quite sure if you want to create a table like the one you showed, or loop every 30min for some other actions. If it is the later one, you can refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153584/how-to-iterate-over-a-timespan-after-days-hours-weeks-and-months-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `timedelta` to generate a range of `datetime` objects:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

start_date = datetime(2016, 6, 9, 5, 0, 0)
for td in (start_date + timedelta(minutes=30*it) for it in xrange(10)):
    print td.strftime("%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M")
```

Output:

```
2016-06-09,05:00
2016-06-09,05:30
2016-06-09,06:00
2016-06-09,06:30
2016-06-09,07:00
2016-06-09,07:30
2016-06-09,08:00
2016-06-09,08:30
2016-06-09,09:00
2016-06-09,09:30
```

Comment: To be python3 compatible you need a parenthesis in print. Also, you need to replace xrange() with range(). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

format = "%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M"

start = datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 10, 0, 0)

minutes = 0

for i in range(6):
    print (start + timedelta(minutes=minutes)).strftime(format)
    minutes += 30
```

Output:

```
$ python timespan.py  
2016-06-10,00:00  
2016-06-10,00:30  
2016-06-10,01:00  
2016-06-10,01:30  
2016-06-10,02:00  
2016-06-10,02:30
```