# Finding Days Per Month From Now Until End Date

Tags: python

I am trying to create an array that will house the days of each month from the CURRENT MONTH until a future date that is specified (for this case I will use 12/31/2022).

So far I am able to set it up to get each day of each month in a given year, but only starting in January.

What I need to have happen is, for example starting now in September, have the array created with days in a month for SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER...DECEMBER of 2022.

The code I have thus far:

```
total = 0
days = []
dayst = []
for i in range(1,13):
    month = datetime.datetime.strptime('{}'.format(i), "%m").strftime("%B")
    length_of_month = calendar.monthrange(MODELYEAR, i)[1]
    total = total + length_of_month
    days.append(length_of_month)
    dayst.append(total)
    totaldays = sum(days)
```

With current output:

```
[31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
```

I essentially just need to make the end time dynamic and shift the start time to current month.

Thank you all!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over a timespan after days, hours, weeks and months in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153584/how-to-iterate-over-a-timespan-after-days-hours-weeks-and-months-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the datetime library to get the number of days between two dates

```
>>> import calendar
>>> from dateutil import rrule
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> end = datetime.strptime('12/31/2022', '%m/%d/%Y')
>>> start = datetime.now()
>>> [calendar.monthrange(dt_i.year, dt_i.month)[1] for dt_i in rrule.rrule(rrule.MONTHLY, dtstart=start, until=end)]
[30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. I am trying to get days PER month not total days.

Comment: There we go! That is what I was looking for, appreciate the addition response.

Comment: @bathtub2007 I have updated the answer. If you find it useful, upvote the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to get the first day of each month of interest, and compute the number of days to the first of the next month after it.

```
import datetime

def days(ending):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    next_month = datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, 1)
    while next_month <= ending:
        month = next_month
        y = month.year
        m = month.month + 1
        if m > 12:
            y += 1
            m = 1
        next_month = datetime.datetime(y, m, 1)
        yield (next_month - month).days
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to determine the days in each month from the current date to a future date. Here's what I think is a very straight-forward way of doing exactly that:

```
import calendar
import datetime


def days_per_month_until_end_date(end_year, end_month, end_day):
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    future_date = datetime.datetime(end_year, end_month, end_day)
    result = []
    for year in range(today.year, future_date.year+1):
        start_month = today.month if year == today.year else 1
        end_month = future_date.month if year == future_date.year else 12
        for month in range(start_month, end_month+1):
            dim = calendar.monthlen(year, month)  # Days In Month
            result.append(dim)
    return result


print(days_per_month_until_end_date(2022, 12, 31))
```

Result printed from running it on 2019-09-16 with the end date as shown):

```
[30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
```