# Need help incorporating SQL in Python loop with global variables in python being cast into the SQL

Tags: python, sql, jupyter-notebook, teradata

I want to automate the query below so that the start and end date can be entered manually but then the query can run on a loop for any given number of months on a monthly basis based on the initial start and end dates given.

I have these two variables in python:

```
start_date = '2022-07-01'
end_date = '2023-06-30'
```

And I have this for loop to parse dates at the monthly level:

```
my_date = datetime.strptime('2022-07-01', "%Y-%m-%d")
for repeat in range(0,12):
    print({datetime.strftime(my_date, "%Y-%m-%d")})
    my_date = my_date + relativedelta(months=+1)
```

The output is like this:

```
{'2022-07-01'}
{'2022-08-01'}
{'2022-09-01'}
{'2022-10-01'}
{'2022-11-01'}
{'2022-12-01'}
{'2023-01-01'}
{'2023-02-01'}
{'2023-03-01'}
{'2023-04-01'}
{'2023-05-01'}
{'2023-06-01'}
```

Now I have this sql query that I am using the variables in:

```
select
a.b
from
c
where a.date between {start_dte} and {end_dte}
 (select
   a.b
    from
   c
    where
    a.date between ({start_dte} - 180 days) and ({end_dte} - 1 month) 
        )
```

This is what I want the query to look like:

```
select
a.b
from
c
where a.date between '2022-07-01' and '2023-06-30'
 (select
   a.b
    from
   c
    where
    a.date between '2022-01-01' and '2023-05-31' 
        )
```

The whole thing looks like this in python:

```
my_date = datetime.strptime('2022-07-01', "%Y-%m-%d")
for repeat in range(0,12):
    print({datetime.strftime(my_date, "%Y-%m-%d")})
    my_date = my_date + relativedelta(months=+1)

start_date = '2022-07-01'
end_date = '2023-06-30'
    
cnxn = pyodb.connect(user,pass)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

sql=f'''
select
    distinct a
    b
from 
    c
    left outer join
   d
        on c.id = d.id
    
where
    c.ind = 'N'
    and c.dte between {start_dte} and {end_dte}
    and d.nme like any ('%dog%')
    and c.a not in 
select
distinct a
from
c
left outer join
   d
        on c.id = d.id
where a.date between {start_dte} and {end_dte}
 (select
   a.b
    from
   c
    where
    a.date between ({start_dte} - 180 days) and ({end_dte} - 1 month) 
        )
'''
```

The date range has to be in `"%Y-%m-%d"` format and I want to loop this query in python for any number of months (12-24 months) without manually having to change the values within the query for every month.

I am trying this to get the second set of dates based on the first set like this:

```
and a.date between date_sub('{start_date}',interval 180 day) and date_sub('{end_date}',interval 30 day)
```

But I get this error:

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Syntax error: expected something between '(' and the string '2021-03-02'.  (-3706) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Any advice on this would be appreciated!
Thank you all!

Comment: the problem is you're not putting the dates in quotes, so it thinks you're doing arithmetic `2022 minus 7 minus 1`

Comment: And the date intervals need to be `INTERVAL 180 DAY` and `INTERVAL 1 MONTH`.

Comment: All the dates are in quotes and my question is how would I go about automating this query for any number of months?

Comment: They're not in quotes. That would be `where a.date between '{start_dte}' and '{end_dte}'`. But you shouldn't substitute variables directly into the SQL. See the linked question for the proper way to use variables in SQL queries.

Comment: But I need the sql query to be run in python since I will be using the data from the query to get loaded into excel.

Comment: And I also need the query to be run on a loop for a months worth of data at a time while keeping the logic sound. So if the number of months in the loop is given as 12 the report will run on a monthly basis from 2022-7-1 to 2023-7-1 while the other dates where it needs to be 180 days prior to the initial start date and the end date being 30 days prior to the initial end date are accommodated for in the loop.

Comment: There are functions in the `date` module for incrementing dates.

Comment: But how would I incorporate a for loop in this situation? I want the query to run on a monthly increment basis for 12 months. How would I do that in Python?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python

Comment: How would I add the sql in that for loop?

Comment: And seems like the solution is iterating over days but I need it at a monthly level
As well as when using variables in SQL when the said variables are coded in python then there is no need to to add parenthesis on the date variables

Comment: You substitute into the SQL the same way as if you're not in a loop.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153584/how-to-iterate-over-a-timespan-after-days-hours-weeks-and-months for iterating by any unit.

Comment: I have the for loop for the date range in python and the query with variables but how do I incorporate them?

Comment: Hey Barmar, so I am using this for the date ranges: and a.date between date_sub('{start_date}',interval 180 day) and date_sub('{end_date}',interval 30 day) But it gives me this error: "ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Syntax error: expected something between '(' and the string '2021-03-02'.  (-3706) (SQLExecDirectW)")" Any ideas?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? `DATE_SUB(..., INTERVAL 30 DAY)` is MySQL syntax, I don't know the equivalent in Teradata.

Comment: Ah ok, I am using teradata; how would I apply math or just formulas to the date ranges in teradata?

Comment: I don't use teradata. I'm sure it's in their documentation.

Comment: Seems like this should have done the trick but it gives me a weird error. I wrote this: `between {start_date} - INTERVAL '180' DAY and {end_date} - INTERVAL '30' DAY` but I get this error: `ProgrammingError: ('25000', '[25000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement.  (-3932) (SQLExecDirectW)')` Any Ideas?

Comment: You STILL need quotes around `{start_date}` and `{end_date}` so they're strings, not numbers.

Comment: That error message sounds like you tried to put multiple queries in the same `cursor.execute()` call.

Comment: Ah yup that was it but it seems like the the syntax still isnt what teradata ingests as I got hit with this error this time `Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Invalid operation for DateTime or Interval.  (-5407) (SQLExecDirectW)')`

Comment: Teradata has an `ADD_MONTHS()` function. https://docs.teradata.com/r/Enterprise_IntelliFlex_VMware/SQL-Date-and-Time-Functions-and-Expressions/DateTime-and-Interval-Functions-and-Expressions

Comment: Do nested queries could as 2 queries? I am now using this: `between ADD_MONTHS('{start_dte}', -6) and ADD_MONTHS('{end_dte}', -1)` but the error message says `('25000', '[25000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement.  (-3932) (SQLExecDirectW)')` So was wondering if nested queries counted as 2 queries.

Comment: No. Queries are separated by `;`.

Comment: Please post a new question to show the full code of what you're trying.

Comment: Hey @Barmar I added the full code in this section: `The whole thing looks like this in python:`

Comment: The 3932 error says Teradata expects a COMMIT or END TRANSACTION statement before you open the cursor, because the connection previously issued what the database considers a DDL statement. And if you are using Jupyter notebook, Instead of pyodbc you may want to look at https://teradata.github.io/jupyterextensions/#/

Comment: So what can be the workaround the error?

Comment: You can add or subtract a number of days from a DATE: `start_dte - 180`

Comment: Seems you need `cnxn.commit()` before the (first) `cursor.open()` but you have not shown enough context to be more specific.